# how to remove a file named "?" in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, command

I created a file named "?", is anybody know how to delete it?

It seems that ? is a special character in linux, I use Redhat as my OS.

I have already tried

```
    rm ?
    rm "?"
    rm \?
```

They all failed and I got the error indicated that the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

find the inode of the file:

```
ls -li
```

then delete the file using inode:

```
find . -inum <inode-number> -exec rm -i {} \;
```

BTW, `rm ?` works for me fine. here is my bash version:

```
# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: When you execute `rm ?`, it removes all the files with a single character in the directory I guess. Try `touch ?`, `touch a` and `rm ?`. It would delete both `?` and `a`

Comment: `BTW, rm ? works for me fine.`  -- That's possibly because that was the only file with a single character in your directory.

Comment: Are you sure this 2 step process will work?

Comment: @anubhava It seems that the `?` was actually some other character.

Comment: @devnull: Oh ok then it was a misleading question.

Comment: @anubhava, is your comment directed at me ? if yes, then Yes, I have encountered many files with junk characters which could not be deleted just by running `rm`. the Only way i could delete 'em is by using inodes and it always worked.

Comment: This worked for me for a file called '-' as well, thanks

Comment: `rm -i` didn't work for me, but you can simplify the find command and use it to delete: `find . -inum 1234 -delete`

Answer (score 5):

`rm \?` and `rm "?"` are both perfectly good ways to delete a file named `?`. If they didn't work, and you still seem to have a file name `?`, then it is most likely that the `?` being shown is not really a `?`, but rather the result of substituting an unprintable character with a `?`. To see what the file is really called (with GNU `ls`) try:

```
ls --quoting-style=escape
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this `rm` command to remove a file named `?`:

```
rm ./\?
```

OR from another directory:

```
rm /path/to/\?
```

Comment: I have tried both, but in doesn't work, however in my friend's machine, the commands I've tried and yours worked out.

Comment: If filename is literal `?` then this command should work. I posted it after myself testing it on OSX and Linux hosts.

Comment: I remember in older bash versions I had to use this command, but now with the bash in my (corporate) development environment, version 4.3.48 this does not work. I have had to use a plain command without escape chars, exactly like follows: `rm ./?`

Comment: It works well on my new bash `4.4.19(1)-release`

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the file by its ***inode*** number. see the output bellow:

```
alplab:~/cad# ls -il
63051 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 12 11:48 ?
alplab:~/cad# find . -inum 63051 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

I used the "find" command to delete the file with the inode number **63051** (the inode belonging to my "?" file).

Comment: `rm -i` didn't work for me, but you can simplify the find command and use it to delete: `find . -inum 1234 -delete`